# I can't find/fix the errors in order to be able to compile it

Tags: tables, math-mode, errors, line-breaking, inline

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


$These are two truth tables for the following:


$\neg (p \vee q)$ is logically equivalent to $(\neg p) \wedge (\neg q)$

\begin{tabular} {|c|c||c|c||c|c|c|}\hline
$p$ & $q$ & $p \vee q$ & $\neg (p \vee q)$ & $\neg p$ & $\neg q$ & $(\neg p) \wedge (\neg q)$\\ \hline
T & T & T & F & F & F & F\\
T & F & T & F & F & T & F\\
F & T & T & F & T & F & F \\
F & F & F & T & T & T & T\\ \hline
\end{tabular}  \vskip .5cm

$\neg (p \implies q)$ is logically equivalent to $p \wedge(\neg q)$

\begin{tabular} {|c|c||c|c||c|c|c|}
\hline
$p$ & $q$ & $(p \implies q)$ & $\neg (p \implies q)$ & $p$ & $\neg q$ & $p \wedge (\neg q)$\\ \hline
T & T & T & F & T & F & F\\ 
T & F & F & T & T & T & T\\ 
F & T & T & F & F & F & F\\ 
F & F & T & F & F & T & F\\ \hline
\end{tabular} \\ \vskip .5cm

$This is some practice using LaTex:
\[
\frac{x^4+5x^3-y}{\cos y-x^2}
\]
\[
\sqrt[\frac{x62}{3}]{\frac{\cos 4}{4.2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Suppress the `$` signs from here: `$These are two truth tables for the following:`, `$This is some practice using LaTex:`, and `\[
$$\sqrt[\frac{x62}{3}]{\frac{\cos 4}{4.2}}$$
\]`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. answer added.

Answer (score 1):

Suppress the spurious `$` signs from the two lines

```
$These are two truth tables for the following:
```

and

```
$This is some practice using LaTex:
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


These are two truth tables for the following:


$\neg (p \vee q)$ is logically equivalent to $(\neg p) \wedge (\neg q)$

\begin{tabular} {|c|c||c|c||c|c|c|}\hline
$p$ & $q$ & $p \vee q$ & $\neg (p \vee q)$ & $\neg p$ & $\neg q$ & $(\neg p) \wedge (\neg q)$\\ \hline
T & T & T & F & F & F & F\\
T & F & T & F & F & T & F\\
F & T & T & F & T & F & F \\
F & F & F & T & T & T & T\\ \hline
\end{tabular}  \vskip .5cm

$\neg (p \implies q)$ is logically equivalent to $p \wedge(\neg q)$

\begin{tabular} {|c|c||c|c||c|c|c|}
\hline
$p$ & $q$ & $(p \implies q)$ & $\neg (p \implies q)$ & $p$ & $\neg q$ & $p \wedge (\neg q)$\\ \hline
T & T & T & F & T & F & F\\ 
T & F & F & T & T & T & T\\ 
F & T & T & F & F & F & F\\ 
F & F & T & F & F & T & F\\ \hline
\end{tabular} \\ \vskip .5cm

This is some practice using \LaTeX:
\[
\frac{x^4+5x^3-y}{\cos y-x^2}
\]
\[
\sqrt[\frac{x62}{3}]{\frac{\cos 4}{4.2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I understand this is a practice document, but just in case, two consecutive displayed expressions must be avoided in a real document.